# How to create abstract classes using abc without using an abstract method?

Tags: python, abstract-class

Using abc, I can create abstract classes using the following:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
class B(A):
    pass

obj = B()
```

This will fail because `B` has not defined the method `foo`.
This mimics the abstract method functionality in Java.

I wanted to know if the abstract class functionality is also present in Python, where instantiation of a class is prevented without having any abstract methods.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean by 'where instantiation of a class is prevented without having any abstract methods' ? you want to enforce the class itself to implement abstractmethods?

Comment: In Java, abstract method and abstract classes are two different concepts. Abstract methods should be defined by the subclasses and abstract classes cannot be instantiated. But in the abc module of python (to my understanding) both are tied together. Is there a way to define an abstract class without decorating any methods as abstract methods?

Comment: Yes. You can. Simply inherit from ABC but don't delcare a method abstract, so it needn't be implemented in its subclasses. If you want the abstract class to enforce the implementation of all methods, decorate all methods. If you want to enforce the implementation of a method that does not belong to an ABC, use `NotImplementedError`

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to create an abstract class in Python is to raise the built-in exception `NotImplementedError`.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('abstract base class')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        # don't call A.__init__ here.
        pass

b = B()
# a = A()  # This will fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can.

- If you want to not enforce method implementation:

Simply inherit from ABC but don't delcare a method abstract, so it needn't be implemented in its subclasses.

- If you want the abstract class to enforce the implementation of all methods:

Decorate all methods.

- If you want to enforce the implementation of a method that does not belong to an ABC:

Raise `NotImplementedError`in the method. This won't prevent instantiation, but usage. However, if you want to prevent it in the instantiation, you should rather use ABC's.

You can also delcare `__init__` an `abstractmethod`, but generally this does not look very useful to me.